# How to bind an edit text in the toolbar in data binding and pass text to the view model

Tags: android, data-binding

I have a custom action toolbar and I'm using data binding. In toolbar is edittext and button. How in my case bind that edittext with viewmodel and pass the value there?

My toolbar in xml is separated. Of course I'have pasted this in activity, but I also have the two fragments and I need working toolbar in these two fragments so this is a reason why I separated that.

toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar   
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
android:id="@+id/city_edit_text"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
android:hint="Search location"
android:textColorHint="@color/colorGrey"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

main_activity:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<data>

    <variable
        name="mainViewModel"
        type="com.example.daniellachacz.weatherapp2.viewmodel.MainViewModel">
    </variable>

    <variable
        name="todayFragmentInterface"
        type="com.example.daniellachacz.weatherapp2.view.TodayFragmentInterface"
        />
</data>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp">
</FrameLayout>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
    android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorWhite"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorWhite">
</com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question properly. 1) could you post the code where you setup the databinding layout? 2) you probably need to wrap the `Toolbar` in xml in `<layout>` tag, have `<data> <variable name="viewModel" type="path.to.your.viewmodel" />` and then you can have 2way databinding with variable in the viewmodel.

Comment: I tried this and it's nice way if you have only one activity, but there are 2 fragments and I need data from bar in both.

Comment: Still not sure if understand ... You can pass interface as the variable and then in your fragments you'd implement the interface. Or if the thing is, you have the toolbar in activity and want to access it from fragments, then it's different.

Please provide more code

Comment: Ok. I just pasted activity_main layout for you.

Comment: so, you have data in activity's viewmodel and you want it in fragments? in that case, you case get the activity's viewmodel via `ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(MainViewModel::class)` and then access to variable you have in activity?

Comment: No. I have edit text field in toolbar and I want bind this with data binding to get value from edit text to the viewmodel.

Comment: then you have to have the toolbar xml with `<layout>` and `<variable name="nameOfVariable" type="yourViewModelClass"/>` tag as I mentioned in first comment. And then in your activity xml you'd have `<include layout="@layout/toolbar" bind:nameOfVariable="@{viewModel}"    android:id="@+id/toolbar" />`